# How to ask Multiple questions to Google Home

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I would like to set up the assistant so that I can have a conversation with it.

Right now, it gives :

- "Hey Google, what is the weather forecast for tomorrow in HongKong?"
- "Tomorrow in Hong Kong, it will be rainy with a max of 35°C and a min
  of 29°C"
- "**Hey Google,** what about the weather forecast for
  sunday?"
- "Sunday, it will be sunny with a max of 35°C and a min of
  29°C"
- "**Hey Google,** what was the maximum temperature today?"
- "Today, the maximum temperature was 35°C"

I would like to find a way so that I do not need to say the trigger word every time, that would then give.

- "Hey Google, what is the weather forecast for tomorrow in HongKong?"
- "Tomorrow in Hong Kong, it will be rainy with a max of 35°C and a min
  of 29°C"
- "What about the weather forecast for
  sunday?"
- "Sunday, it will be sunny with a max of 35°C and a min of
  29°C"
- "What was the maximum temperature today?"
- "Today, the maximum temperature was 35°C"

Is that possible? if yes, can I set the delay during which the Google home remains listening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now possible with the [continued conversations feature](https://www.cnet.com/news/google-home-continued-conversation-setting-keeps-the-mic-hot/) is deployed, announced at Google I/O 2018.

If continued conversations are enabled on your Google Home, the microphone will continue to listen for 8 seconds after the reply (or until you say "thank you", if you wish to prematurely stop it listening). A demonstration of the new flow is avaiable [here, at AndroidPolice](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/05/08/google-assistant-gets-conversational-will-soon-listen-consecutive-requests/), where it's demonstrated that the following conversation could work:

> Hey Google, did the Warriors win?
>
> *Yes, the Warriors won 118 to 92 last Sunday against the Pelicans.*
>
> Nice, when's their next game?
>
> *The Warriors' next game is today at 7:30pm, where they will be playing the Pelicans.*

Comment: Thanks, I mark it as answer even though it is not yet a possible solution, but at least I know what to look for.

Comment: It is now possible!! although limited to 3 questions if I am not mistaken